# Was Governor Pryce's character inspired by Colonel Spalko?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, star-wars-rebels, indiana-jones, character-similarity

Is there any official confirmation that the character of **Arihnda Pryce**, the governor of Lothal in *Star Wars Rebels* was inspired by the character of the KGB Colonel Doctor **Irina Spalko** in *Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull*? They sure look very much alike.

[image]

Comment: I can't find any *official* confirmation, but yeah, obviously intended to be her.